# Retrieving the new ID from a SQLDataAdaptor.Update

Tags: sql, ado.net

How would you go about retrieving the @@IDENTITY value for each row when the SQLDataAdapater.Update is executed on a table?

eg. Is it possible to modify/intercept the InsertCommand, generated by the SQLCommandBuilder, to say add an output parameter, and then retrieve its value in the da.RowUpdated event???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill Vaughn knows a thing or two about this. They key is tweaking your InsertCommand.

See ["Managing an @@IDENTITY Crisis"](http://www.betav.com/Files/Content/Articles/Managing%20and%20Identity%20Crisis.pdf).

Note: the actual solution uses SCOPE_IDENTITY() in order to be trigger-safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is an article that has proven to be quite useful, where the trick of "tweaking the InsertCommand" is explained, as well as the trick to set the query to "Scalar"

[MSDN Article (in VB.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581778.aspx#aspnet_tutorial01_dataaccesslayer_vb_topic5)

Bye!

Peter